# List all posts in custom post type by taxonomy in 2 columns

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I’m trying to get all custom posts by their taxonomy and then put the first two tax in one column and the rest in the second column. But my code loops everything and I get multiple divs. Ideas?

Here's my code :

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$post_type = 'myposttype';
$tax = 'mytaxonomy';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax,'hide_empty=0');

if ($tax_terms) {
  foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => $post_type,
      "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <div class="column1">
    <?php
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      if( ($tax_term->name == 'first_taxterm') || ($tax_term->name == 'second_taxterm')  ) {
      echo "<h2 class=\"tax_term-heading\" id=\"".$tax_term->slug."\"> $tax_term->name </h2>";
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
      endwhile;
      } else {?>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <?php
      echo "<h2 class=\"tax_term-heading\" id=\"".$tax_term->slug."\"> $tax_term->name </h2>";
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
      endwhile; }?>
    </div><?php
    }
    wp_reset_query();
  }
}
?>
```

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way, so I use multiple query like this...

```
<?php
    $args=array(
      'trend-categories' => 'flowers',
      'post_type' => 'trend',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      echo '<h2> TITLE BIG </h2><ul>';
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a class="hey" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cut your wp_query based on your number of $tax

Comment: wouldn't it be too redundant ?